# Error when using twitter User Stream in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component, mule-cluster

I am running the process where I have the twitter as the streaming inbound endpoint capturing all the user sream or the user events .

I sometime get the below errors

WARN  2014-11-19 11:52:05,716 [Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]] org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager: Notification not enqueued after ServerNotificationManager disposal: PipelineMessageNotification{action=pipeline process start, resourceId=CaptureTweets, serverId=null, timestamp=1416378125716}
WARN  2014-11-19 11:52:05,736 [Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]] org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager: Notification not enqueued after ServerNotificationManager disposal: PipelineMessageNotification{action=pipeline process complete, resourceId=CaptureTweets, serverId=null, timestamp=1416378125736}
ERROR 2014-11-19 11:52:05,736 [Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]] org.mule.twitter.adapters.TwitterConnectorConnectionIdentifierAdapter: org.mule.api.MessagingException: Cannot process event as "CaptureTweets" is stopped (org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException). Message payload is of type: UserEvent
org.apache.commons.lang.UnhandledException: org.mule.api.MessagingException: Cannot process event as "CaptureTweets" is stopped (org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException). Message payload is of type: UserEvent
    at org.mule.twitter.TwitterConnector$SoftCallback.process(TwitterConnector.java:1270)
    at org.mule.twitter.TwitterConnector$1.onStatus(TwitterConnector.java:893)
    at twitter4j.StatusStreamImpl.onStatus(StatusStreamImpl.java:75)
    at twitter4j.StatusStreamBase$1.run(StatusStreamBase.java:114)
    at twitter4j.internal.async.ExecuteThread.run(DispatcherImpl.java:116)
Caused by: org.mule.api.MessagingException: Cannot process event as "CaptureTweets" is stopped (org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException). Message payload is of type: UserEvent
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1.process(AbstractPipeline.java:109)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$3.process(AbstractPipeline.java:207)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.processor.AbstractListeningMessageProcessor.processEvent(AbstractListeningMessageProcessor.java:150)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.processor.AbstractListeningMessageProcessor.process(AbstractListeningMessageProcessor.java:76)
    at org.mule.twitter.TwitterConnector$SoftCallback.process(TwitterConnector.java:1268)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Cannot process event as "CaptureTweets" is stopped
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$ProcessIfPipelineStartedMessageProcessor.handleUnaccepted(AbstractPipeline.java:400)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    ... 25 more

not sure of the error and need more information on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `<json:object-to-json-transformer>` to transform Twitter data
Could you pls check this link to get the idea of connecting Mule with Twitter :- http://www.whishworks.com/blog/integration-with-twitter-using-mule-esb/